# Vagrant boots the wrong VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Picture the following scenario:

- Freshly installed, untampered VirtualBox installation
- Freshly installed Vagrant 1.0.6 through gem

And now I try this:

- `vagrant box add box_one [url to box one]`
- `vagrant init box_one`
- `vagrant up`

So far, so good. `box_one` works nicely. It shows up in the VirtualBox Manager, all the port forwardings are set correctly, I can ssh into it, the web server runs - everything is peachy.

- `vagrant halt`
- `rm Vagrantfile`

As far as I understand, this should enable me to do this:

- `vagrant box add box_two [url to box two]`
- `vagrant init box_two`
- `vagrant up`

and use `box_two`. But instead, it clearly uses the configuration of `box_two` - different ports are forwarded - but it boots the virtual machine of `box_one`. And in the VirtualBox Manager it shows two machines with different ids - but both are the virtual machines of `box_one`.

It seems to work for my coworkers, so something on my machine must be triggering that bug. (Or I do something weird, who knows.)

Does anyone have ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 9):

Okay, my error was that I tried to do that in the same directory. This way it kept using the same `.vagrant` file - so the fix is either to keep deleting the `.vagrant` file or run the vagrant actions in different directories.

Comment: Thanks for this, had a similar problem after I copied directory with Vagrant file to a new project, and it kept booting up the existing VM (with new config) and would not run both at the same time. Deleting .vagrant directory helped to solve this problem.

Comment: Copy your setup with the whole directory for a new box, cry. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar problem when running Vagrant from two unrelated directories (each with its own local, distinct `Vagrantfile` and `.vagrant` directory) -- sometimes Vagrant connects to the wrong VM altogether. This happens inconsistently but frequently for me running Vagrant 1.5.x on OSX.

If you see this kind of behavior, the only way I've found to solve it is to add a little more information to the existing Vagrantfile.  In my case, the problem happened when a Vagrantfile looked like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "some-box-name"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8001
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
  end
end
```

And was resolved by adding a line that sets `vb.name`:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "some-box-name"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8001
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.name = "x1_165165261578"  ## added this line
  end
end
```

Apparently Vagrant uses the Virtualbox box name to identify the box, but when it isn't given uses another identifier (maybe the `"default"` Vagrant box name?).  This is strange because the unique ID for the VM is stored in `.vagrant/....../id` and is an absolute identifier.  This must be a bug.

Knowing this can happen -- it's a good practice to verify which VM you're using right after making a Vagrant connection, e.g. by putting the unique machine name in the prompt or some other way.  If you have many similar machines, you may not notice you're using the wrong one until you've done something really bad like apply changes you meant for a test environment to production!